# Using XML to feed a Graphical form/template

Tags: xml, xcode, user-interface, templates, xquery

So I use a program that has templates that are displayed like this:
[template example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5nKQ.png)
The templates are based on XML which you can export.

What I want to be able to do is take the exported XML and create my own viewer which is similar to this one and use the XML to view outside of the software it comes from. I have looked but can't find much on how to do this.

```
    <templates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" systemVersionId="4" mkbVersion="170.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.e-mis.com/emisopen">
    <id>03dc83f1-9de5-47da-92de-681486ce658e</id>
    <templateName>test template</templateName>
    <creationTime>2020-03-15T14:56:54.7105576+00:00</creationTime>
    <author>
        <system>
            <systemType>EMISWEB</systemType>
            <displayName>test, test (Dr)</displayName>
        </system>
    </author>
    <definition>
        <template>
            <page>
                <page>
                    <title>COVID19 - NICE(NG165)</title>
                    <panel>
                        <promptForDate>false</promptForDate>
                        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                        <panel>
                            <title>Links and guidance</title>
                            <createComponentsAsChildren>false</createComponentsAsChildren>
                            <component>
                                <id>3c3c878a-a71e-4c69-a54a-6cd56903081f</id>
                                <label>We are continually collating the latest evidence and handy links for COVID19 here </label>
                                <promptForDate>false</promptForDate>
                                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                                <hyperlink>
                                    <title>We are continually collating the latest evidence and handy links for COVID19 here </title>
                                    <URL></URL>
                                </hyperlink>
                            </component>
                            <component>
                                <id>01935239-f461-4624-b230-110a5bdd03c2</id>
                                <label>There is a lot of evidence based supporting information on this template. Please take your time to get familiar with it before use.  
(Version updated 20/01/2021)
Data marked ** is included in national surveillance uploads so complete if relevant
</label>
                                <promptForDate>false</promptForDate>
                                <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                                <textDisplay>
                                    <text>{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\colortbl ;\red87\green85\blue81;\red237\green28\blue36;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\cf1\f0\fs16 There is a lot of evidence based supporting information on this template. Please take your time to get familiar with it before use.  \par
(Version updated 20/01/2021)\fs18\par
\cf2\b Data marked ** is included in national surveillance uploads so complete if relevant\cf1\b0\par
\cf0\par
}
</text>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using RTF to describe the rendering, rather than CSS which is surely far more portable?

Comment: That's what the software uses. It was made in 2011. Not in my control, unfortunately, but completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

XForms can be used to render such XML documents in a browser. XSLTForms (my own implementation, at https://github.com/AlainCouthures/declarative4all/raw/master/public/direct/xsltforms.zip) does not yet support RTF output but it could easily be added with some library such as https://github.com/tbluemel/rtf.js

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.